# Mapping a list of string key-value pairs with Razor / form post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have some HTML in my Razor view that is basically 3 rows of a pair of Select and Input elements:
*(There could be more than 3)*

```
<select name="SocialNetwork[1]">
    <option>Skype</option>
    <option>Twitter</option>
    <option>Facebook</option>
</select>

<input name="SocialNetworkUsername[1]" type="text" />

<select name="SocialNetwork[2]">
    <option>Skype</option>
    <option>Twitter</option>
    <option>Facebook</option>
</select>

<input name="SocialNetworkUsername[2]" type="text" />

<select name="SocialNetwork[3]">
    <option>Skype</option>
    <option>Twitter</option>
    <option>Facebook</option>
</select>

<input name="SocialNetworkUsername[3]" type="text" />
```

When the form is posted to my controller method:

```
public ActionResult SaveDetails(MyModel model)
{
}
```

How can I 'map' the values of SocialNetwork | SocialNetworkUsername to a model?
Something like:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string,string> SocialNetworks { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not 'stuck' using a dictionary if there is something more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You can use an editor template to achieve this.

the editor template will allow you to loop through a list of social networks in your main view and use the @Html.EditorFor helper to render out your dropdown lists and make model binding easy.

To start with your model should represent a single Social Network

In your model you need  properties to contain the dropdown list values, and a property for the selected value. You'll also need a property to contain the SocialNetworkUsername

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SocialNetworks { get; set; }
public string SelectedSocialNetwork { get; set; }

public string SocialNetworkUserName { get; set; }
```

To make your editor template add a new folder /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates

In the EditorTemplates folder create a new view with the name MyClass (or whatever your model class name is)

You need to follow these naming conventions as there is no other configuration required for the editor template to work.

In MyClass.cshtml you need to allow editing of a single social network

```
@model MyModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSocialNetwork, Model.SocialNetworks)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SocialNetworkUserName)
```

Then in your main view you use a List of MyModel as the model for the view and use a for loop to render out your editor templates.

```
@model List<MyModel>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        Html.EditorFor(Model[i])
    }
}
```

In your controller just change your action method parameter to accept a List of MyClass and model binding should just magically work ;)

Comment: -1 - This assumes there is ONE SelectedSocialNetwork. This question asks how to receive a list of them back from the form (there could be 1-20 for example)

Comment: Sorry i didn't read the question properly. I've edited my answer.